# enablecolumns and QueryBuilder in TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I have a question about enablecolumns and QueryBuilder in TYPO3 9.5:

In the TCA I defined the enablecolumns:

```
    'ctrl' => [
      'title'       => '....'
      'tstamp'          => 'tstamp',
      'crdate'          => 'crdate',
      'versioningWS'        => 2,
      'versioning_followPages'  => true,
      'origUid'             => 't3_origuid',
      'languageField'   => 'sys_language_uid',
      'transOrigPointerField'   => 'l18n_parent',
      'transOrigDiffSourceField'    => 'l18n_diffsource',
      'delete'          => 'deleted',
      'enablecolumns' => [
        'disabled' => 'hidden',
        'fe_group' => 'fe_group',
      ],
    ]
```

In the repository I create a custom Query:

```
    $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_myext_domain_model_table'); 
    $result = $queryBuilder
      ->select('*')
      ->from('tx_myext_domain_model_table')
      ->where($where)
      ->execute();
```

If I debug the SQL with

```
$queryBuilder->getSQL();
```

I see the deleted, and hidden conditions but no fe_group

If I add

```
$queryBuilder
->getRestrictions()
->removeAll()
->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendGroupRestriction::class))
->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DeletedRestriction::class))
->add(GeneralUtility::makeInstance(HiddenRestriction::class));
```

before the execution of the query, the fe_groups condition ist added.

What am I missing?

Thank you
Christian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `QueryBuilder` by default uses the `DefaultRestrictionContainer` which adds only the following restrictions:

```php
protected $defaultRestrictionTypes = [
    DeletedRestriction::class,
    HiddenRestriction::class,
    StartTimeRestriction::class,
    EndTimeRestriction::class
];
```

References:

- https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/QueryBuilder.php#L86
- https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/DefaultRestrictionContainer.php#L28-L33

What you're probably looking for is the `FrontendRestrictionContainer` which uses the following default restrictions:

```php
protected $defaultRestrictionTypes = [
    DeletedRestriction::class,
    FrontendWorkspaceRestriction::class,
    HiddenRestriction::class,
    StartTimeRestriction::class,
    EndTimeRestriction::class,
    FrontendGroupRestriction::class,
];
```

Reference: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/9.5/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/Query/Restriction/FrontendRestrictionContainer.php#L33-L40

A possible solution would be to use this container instead of the default one:

```php
$container = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendRestrictionContainer::class);
$queryBuilder->setRestrictions($container);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not believe that it is that way. I don‘t understand why hidden and deleted are set and fe_group not...